# React : Is there a difference between passing the usestate hook directly to parent vs passing a function in which calling usestate?

Tags: reactjs

Is there any (performance) difference of passing the use state hook directly to parent vs passing a function to parent in which I call use state setter?

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    
    return <Child onSelect={setName}/>
};
```

vs

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);
    const handleName = (input) => {
        setName(input)
    };
    
    return <Child onSelect={handleName}/>
};
```

```
const Child = ({onSelect}) => {
    return (
        //code to get name 
        <Button onClick={() => onSelect(name)}/>
    )
}
```

Comment: Looks the same to me, but the first option is better. As handleName calls setName with the same argument it recieves, passing setName directly is fine. I don't think there is any difference in performance.

Comment: You could wrap handleName in a useCallback otherwise it will be recreated every render, and could cause other rerenders down the line

Comment: In the second options you are re-creating the `handleName` function so it is a different prop you are passing to the `Child` component. This means that the Child component will have to re-render each time.

Comment: Even simple solution pass all hooks through useContext hooks .

Answer (score 0):

---

Ideally you should pass function to the child, performance is generally not an issue.

Passing a function is better, since the child does not have to know the details about parent's update method.

- This makes refactoring the parent easier, parent can use a state management library like redux, jotai etc and child wont change
- makes child more testable

This is related to SOLID principles and i[nversion of control](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/inversion-of-control), it will help you write more maintianable code.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is better than the second one in some case
Let's suppose for your child component you have added a memo for it to ensure it'n not being re-rendered unless its props are changing
First case will not re-render the Child component but the second one will re-render the child component when the parent is re-rendered

Comment: Note : you can go with second approach with adding useCallback to your update function to avoid unnecessary re-renders

Answer (score 0):

I think there will be no performance difference. But second approach is preferable when you want to do few more actions after setting state i.e. for code readability (since you can write them in arrow function too). setName internally calls  dispatchSetState() which is again a function to set state value.